# make the post index page as root path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I want to make the post index page the root page and also get the /posts to redirect to the root path as well
the prefix of the index is posts...
I try this one in the routes(but i dont know if it is the right way)

```
root "posts#index'
resources :posts, except: [:index]
```

so now i get the root for index but the /posts not working ... instead of getting the error i want it to redirect to the root page... 
here is my posts routes after changing my routes file...

```
 root GET    /                              posts#index
               posts POST   /posts(.:format)               posts#create
            new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)           posts#new
           edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)      posts#edit
                post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#show
                     PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                     PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                     DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#destroy
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: root path and index path are same so you can't get the  /posts url in posts index view

Comment: @ArupRakshit this is what I get No route matches [GET] "/posts"

Comment: @Vishal how they are same?? the index is for posts controller...

Answer (score 1):

change

```
root "posts#index"
resources :posts, except: [:index]
```

to

```
root "posts#index"
resources :posts
```

Comment: thanks that is better but I see that now posts controller index action has two routes... is that ok? what I meant is instead of getting the routes error when going to /posts,,, I want this link to redirect to the root and have just one routes...is that possible?

Comment: App always have root. your app's root is root "posts#index", so when ever you start the app.. this page shows.. but if you want to redirect again to index path than you have to write root_path.

Comment: and your question's answer is yes. you can redirect to posts index when you run http://localhost:3000/posts . there should not be error.. but your post must have index method and in your route file resources :posts

Comment: Thank you a lot for that ;)